# Rendering text that is a list with Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

My test from api:

```
"- 
 Flight for two with a certified flight instructor - 
 Approximately 1.5 hours of airtime in a Socata TB-10 Tobago - 
 Opportunity for one passenger to control the plane during part of flight; no experience necessary - 
 Learn about the flight plan, instrumentation, and basic aircraft control during preflight instruction - 
 Epic photo ops above spectacular natural scenery and world-famous sites - 
 Aerial views of downtown LA, the Hollywood sign, film studios, Griffith Observatory, Beverly Hills, Dodger Stadium, the coast, and more "
```

I want to render this as a list with Reactjs. I have tried the css `white-space` property with no luck:

```
- 
 Flight for two with a certified flight instructor
- 
 Approximately 1.5 hours of airtime in a Socata TB-10 Tobago
- 
 Opportunity for one passenger to control the plane during part of flight; no experience necessary
- 
 Learn about the flight plan, instrumentation, and basic aircraft control during preflight instruction
- 
 Epic photo ops above spectacular natural scenery and world-famous sites
- 
 Aerial views of downtown LA, the Hollywood sign, film studios, Griffith Observatory, Beverly Hills, Dodger Stadium, the coast, and more
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You want to turn a string into a list? `.split('\n')` ?

Comment: @azium i tried that and works. my fear is that, given it's a user entered data, i may have unexpected behavior (multiline list item)

Comment: I don't understand then.. what determines which characters in the string belong to which item in the list? What do you mean by list anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what are you looking for:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  getList = () => {
    let apiData = `- 
    Flight for two with a certified flight instructor - 
    Approximately 1.5 hours of airtime in a Socata TB-10 Tobago - 
    Opportunity for one passenger to control the plane during part of flight; no experience necessary - 
    Learn about the flight plan, instrumentation, and basic aircraft control during preflight instruction - 
    Epic photo ops above spectacular natural scenery and world-famous sites - 
    Aerial views of downtown LA, the Hollywood sign, film studios, Griffith Observatory, Beverly Hills, Dodger Stadium, the coast, and more `;

    return apiData.split("\n").map(item => <li> {item} </li>);
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.getList()}</div>;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-lovelace-tmdj5)